What is original sin based on Genesis 3?
In Genesis we read,

"And He said to Adam, “Because you listened to your wife’s voice and
ate from the tree about which I commanded you, ‘Do not eat from it"

I have not found the passage were God says because you have sinned to Adam. Can this be explained from this passage? There is no reference in the Old Testament that explains this event to be called original sin.

That's why Jews call it the "first sin." The term "original sin" was coined by St. Augustine in the 5th c. based on Paul's teaching that in 1 Corinthians 15 and Romans etc. https://www.arcaneknowledge.org/catholic/original.htm

@Dan, this is from the site you provided. "The doctrine of original sin was no invention of St. Augustine, though the Bishop of Hippo did much to elaborate this dogma."

"There is no reference in the old testament that explains this event to be called original sin." — That's because the original sin doctrine is of Christian origin. ¶Judaism does believe that mankind has inherited a tendency to sin, but the Christian doctrine also include mankind inheriting the guilt for that first sin. They are two quite different concepts.

This question isn't about what Genesis 3:17 says; it is about what the rest of the Torah doesn't say. So the question really isn't suitable for this site in its current form.

@RayButterworth- So from the words of Jesus, "In this way, you have revoked God’s word because of your tradition."

The phrase "original sin" does not occur in the Bible.  It is a more modern theological construct.

"you must not eat Unrestricted freedom does not exist. Man is called upon by God to exercise restraint and self-discipline in the gratification of his appetite. This prohibition is the paradigm for the future Torah legislation relating to the dietary laws." --
Sarna, N. M. (1989). Genesis (p. 21). Jewish Publication Society.
